# Understanding the GLM 4x4 Matrix functions

Tags: c++, math, matrix, glm-math

I am having trouble understanding a certain element of the GLM Matrix functions while trying to replicate some of its math to finish off my Matrix4 class for an assignment. Take this Rotate function.

```
    tmat4x4<T, P> const & m,
    T angle,
    tvec3<T, P> const & v

    T const a = angle;
    T const c = cos(a);
    T const s = sin(a);

    tvec3<T, P> axis(normalize(v));
    tvec3<T, P> temp((T(1) - c) * axis);

    tmat4x4<T, P> Rotate(uninitialize);
    Rotate[0][0] = c + temp[0] * axis[0];
    Rotate[0][1] = 0 + temp[0] * axis[1] + s * axis[2];
    Rotate[0][2] = 0 + temp[0] * axis[2] - s * axis[1];

    Rotate[1][0] = 0 + temp[1] * axis[0] - s * axis[2];
    Rotate[1][1] = c + temp[1] * axis[1];
    Rotate[1][2] = 0 + temp[1] * axis[2] + s * axis[0];

    Rotate[2][0] = 0 + temp[2] * axis[0] + s * axis[1];
    Rotate[2][1] = 0 + temp[2] * axis[1] - s * axis[0];
    Rotate[2][2] = c + temp[2] * axis[2];

    tmat4x4<T, P> Result(uninitialize);
    Result[0] = m[0] * Rotate[0][0] + m[1] * Rotate[0][1] + m[2] * Rotate[0][2];
    Result[1] = m[0] * Rotate[1][0] + m[1] * Rotate[1][1] + m[2] * Rotate[1][2];
    Result[2] = m[0] * Rotate[2][0] + m[1] * Rotate[2][1] + m[2] * Rotate[2][2];
    Result[3] = m[3];
```

Or the Translate function (v is a vector)

```
    tmat4x4<T, P> const & m,
    tvec3<T, P> const & v

    Result[3] = m[0] * v[0] + m[1] * v[1] + m[2] * v[2] + m[3];
```

The part I am having trouble understanding is what part of the matrix Result[1] or m[0] access. Does Result[1] = Result[1][1]? It's used in many functions, and it's the last part of these functions I am having trouble with.

How are they handling using a single number to access an element in a 2D array, and what element is that single number accessing?

Comment: I've written a full matrix4 class, I understand matrix vector multiplication. I just don't understand GLM's way of having accessing certain elements of the 2D array with just 1 number. I'll clarify the original post.

Comment: They are 2D arrays, [a][b], a is the row, b is the column. What I don't understand is what element they access when they request [c]. I need to know this to replicate this specific function into my own Matrix4 class (which also uses a 2D array) for my assignment. I included some, but GLM source code is too long to copy-paste into this post.

Comment: Run debugger, put breakpoint to that line and see what's the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code defining the template `tmat4x4<T,P>`, with type `T` and precision `P`, [that is available here](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_mat4x4.hpp), answers your question.

As you can see line 60, the actual data contents of a `tmat4x4` are defined as an array of 4 `col_type` elements, and accessing `m[i]` (defined line 96 as returning `col_type &`) [returns the full i-th column](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_mat4x4.inl#L323).

`col_type` is typedef'd to `tvec4<T,P>`, whose code [is available here](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec4.hpp), and also [defines a `[]` access operator](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec4.inl#L211) that returns type `T &`, thus when you write `m[a][b]` you say "give me the column a, and therein the element b".

`tvec4<T,P>` also [defines a binary `*` operator](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec4.hpp#L301), so it makes sense to take the whole vector and multiply it by some scalar of type `U`, which is [multiplying each element of the vector by that scalar](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec4.inl#L329).

So in order to answer your question, `Result[1]` is not `Result[1][1]` but rather `Result[1][1..4]` (even though that's not proper C++).

Comment: Thankyou for this and David explaining this, it all clicked, its just Vector4 x Vector4/3 operations. Thank god I wrote a Vector4 class. Regardless, I should be able to either split it into individual elements, or use my Vector4 class for the operations.

Interestingly, while you guys say its column major, the breakpoint result (which I had forgotten worked on include files) suggests its row major, with   

    Result[0] = m[0] * Rotate[0][0] + m[1] * Rotate[0][1] + m[2] * Rotate[0][2];  

working out the first row (according to VS2015 when I hover over Result).

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions named `tmat4x4<T, P>::operator[]`. One has return type `tmat4x4<T>::col_type&` and the other has return type `tmat4x4<T>::col_type const&`. So `m[1]` does not denote a single element of a matrix; rather, it denotes an entire column (four elements) of a matrix, and you can perform mathematical column-vector operations on it.